# можно ли импортировать .txt или .ini файл как .py файл?

Tags: python

Есть список констрант и настроек, которые хотелось бы добавлять в py файл через import,
но каждый раз открывать с блокнота не оч удобно.
Есть ли возможность импортировать .txt или .ini файл как .py файл?
Как себя поведет программа при сборке через nuitka или Pyinstaller?

Вот пример переименования:

```
import os
os.rename('tt.txt', 'tt.py')
from tt import *
print(x)
os.rename('tt.py', 'tt.txt')
```

Comment: к примеру: можно наверное переименовывать файл настроек из ini в py перед импортом.

Comment: Если очень хочется, то можно загрузить файл в память и выполнить через exec. Но лучше не использовать исполняемый формат для хранения настроек.

Comment: Накидайте пример, не оч понимаю

Comment: `with open('text.txt') as file: exec(file.read())`

Comment: почему бы не сохранять сразу в `.py`

Comment: Блокнот умеет открывать любые файлы, нужно просто указать ему в свойствах, что можно открывать .py

Answer (score 0):

Можно, конечно, переименовывать, но лучше просто использовать модуль, например, `configparser`, который как раз и предназначем для работы с файлыми настроек.

А если хочется импортировать, то можно сразу назвать файл на .py.

Comment: так в том то и дело, configparser нужно разжевывать.... import в этом плане лучше, но гораздо удобней просто открыть файл и изменить значения.